# Contour integration on semicircle as R -> infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-1-iz}{z^3}$$

What is the value of $$\int_{C} f(z) dz$$ if C is the arc of the semicircle with radius $R\to \infty$ ,going counterclockwise from point (R,0) to (-R,0)

Attempt: I am making D = C + C' where C' is a line going from (-R,0) to (R,0). From there, I tried to use the residue theorem  $\int_{C} f(z) dz + \int_{C'} f(z) dz = \pi i$ buth I cannot find the value of $\int_{C'} f(z) dz$ as R approach infinity

any help is appreciated. Thx

Comment: Your function has a singularity at $z=0$, and this point lies on the $C'$ you chose, so you may have to choose some other path

Comment: I tried to make a smaller half circle from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$  so that the point of singularity is out of the path but I still cannot find the value. I wonder if R-> infinity is the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\int_Cf(z)dz=\int_0^\pi f(Re^{it})iRe^{it}dt$$
for any $z=Re^{it}$ on $C$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}&|f(Re^{it})iRe^{it}|=\frac{|e^{iRe^{it}}-1-iRe^{it}|}{R^2}=\frac{|e^{iR\cos t}e^{-R\sin t}-1-iRe^{it}|}{R^2}\\
\leq &\frac{|e^{iR\cos t}e^{-R\sin t}|+1+|iRe^{it}|}{R^2}=\frac{e^{-R\sin t}+1+R}{R^2}\\
\leq &\frac{2+R}{R^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Then it follows that
$$\left|\int_C f(z)dz\right|\leq \int_0^\pi |f(Re^{it})iRe^{it}|dt\leq \pi\frac{2+R}{R^2}\to 0$$